# friend of templated class in anonymous namespace

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, language-lawyer, friend

When declaring a class `A` as friend of a class `B`, while `A` is defined inside an anonymous namespace and `B` outside, some compilers produce an error "*protected member inaccessible*" while others do not produce any error or warning. The situation changes if either `A` or `B` or both are templates:

```cpp
namespace {
  template <class T>
  struct A {
    template <class BB>
    void foo(BB const& b) { b.bar(); }
  };
} // end anonymous namespace

template <class T>
class B {
  template <class> friend struct A;

protected:
  void bar() const {}
};

int main() {
  A<int> a;
  a.foo(B<int>{});
}
```

1. `A` and `B` are both templates. Then Intel icc 18: **error** `#308: function "B<T>::bar [with T=int]" is inaccessible`, gcc 7.2: no error, clang 5.0: no error
2. `A` is no template while `B` is template: Intel icc 18: no error, gcc 7.2: **error**: `'void B<T>::bar() const [with T = int]' is protected within this context`, clang 5: no error
3. `A` is a template while `B` is not: Intel icc 18: **error** `#308`, gcc 7.2: **error**, clang 5: no error
4. neither `A` nor `B` are templates: Intel icc 18: no error, gcc 7.2: **error**, clang 5: no error
5. neither `A` nor `B` are templates (as in 4.) but location of `A` and `B` exchanged: Intel icc 18: **error** `#308`, gcc 7.2: **error**, clang 5: **error**: `'bar' is a protected member of 'B'`
6. `A` and `B` are both templates (as in 1.) but location of `A` and `B` exchanged: Intel icc 18: **error** `#308`, gcc 7.2: no error, clang 5: **error**

See the example in the compiler explorer: https://godbolt.org/g/6Zdr3c and https://godbolt.org/g/BRqf78 for the case 6.

So, what is the correct behavior? Which compiler is correct?

Comment: Clang is correct everywhere, this is one of the many [gcc template access bugs](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59002). Though I do not see a gcc error in (4) or (5)?

Comment: @Barry Is the standard clear about that? You certainly know which rules apply no?

Comment: Fiddled around with gcc, and apparently the bug also happens when using *inline namespaces* and *using directives*, but not with *using declarations*.

Comment: What do you mean "location of `A` and `B` exchanged"?

Comment: @xskxzr: Define the class `B` above the anonymous namespace with the class `A` inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can judge from the standard the given code is correct in cases 1-4 and should compile without diagnostics:

The definition of unnamed namespaces (7.3.1.1:1) state that an unnamed namespace definition is equivalent to defining a named namespace with a name unique to the translation unit and then importing this namespace with a using directive.

This will make the declaration of `A` accessible in the global scope, and according to paragraph 11.3:9

> A name nominated by a friend declaration shall be accessible in the scope of the class containing the friend declaration.

Thus the parameterized class `A` is a friend of `B` and should be able to access `B::bar`

In case 5 there is a difference. As far as I can see, the friend declaration declares a new parameterized class `A` in the enclosing scope which is different from the class `A` in the unnamed namespace.

Comment: I have rechecked clang for case 5 and found that it gives an error. As far as I understand you correctly, this is correct behavior. An additional case 6 also gives an error with clang, but not with gcc.

Comment: @spraetor Both 5 and 6 should give errors. The friend declaration in `B` also acts as a forward declaration of `A` in the enclosing namespace, i.e. the global namespace. The later declaration of `A` is inside an unnamed namespace and will not match this forward declaration.